# In IntelliJ, how to use a surround Live template without use $SELECTION$ in the template body?

Tags: intellij-idea

I didn't found the way to use the $SELECTION$ variable without use it in the template.
I can modify SELECTION in another variable and use this variable in the template. But if I don't use the $SELECTION$ in the template, the template is not available in the "Surround With" menu.

Is there a way to use a Live template which can take in parameter the user SELECTION without display it in the template ?

The goal is to store and apply a dozen of regex/replace.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems to be a bug of my current IntelliJ Idea version. I use the version 2019.2.

[WebStorm Live Template $SELECTION$ Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55480922/webstorm-live-template-selection-regular-expression/71843085#71843085)